# Uninitialized constant ActionCable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I have found similar questions to this but none of the answers fixed the problem. I have an existing project I upgraded from v4.2.5 to 5.1.5. I wanted to add a chatroom using the [Site Point tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/create-a-chat-app-with-rails-5-actioncable-and-devise/) but am having issues with ActionCable. Whenever I start up my server, it crashes with the following error:

```
/home/ubuntu/workspace/config/routes.rb:39:in `block in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant ActionCable (NameError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:434:in `instance_exec'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:434:in `eval_block'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:412:in `draw'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config/routes.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config.ru:3:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/rack-1.6.9/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/rack-1.6.9/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config.ru:in `new'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config.ru:in `<main>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/rack-1.6.9/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/rack-1.6.9/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/rack-1.6.9/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/rack-1.6.9/lib/rack/server.rb:300:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/rack-1.6.9/lib/rack/server.rb:209:in `app'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/rack-1.6.9/lib/rack/server.rb:337:in `wrapped_app'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:139:in `log_to_stdout'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:78:in `start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I already manually created the following files to set up ActionCable:

```
# app/channels/application_cable/channel.rb
module ApplicationCable
  class Channel < ActionCable::Channel::Base
  end
end
```

and

```
# app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

        def connect
          self.current_user = find_verified_user
          logger.add_tags 'ActionCable', current_user.email
        end

        protected

        def find_verified_user # this checks whether a user is authenticated with devise
          if verified_user = env['warden'].user
            verified_user
          else
            reject_unauthorized_connection
          end
        end
  end
end
```

I have tried requiring both "action_cable" and "action_cable/engine" in the top of my config/application.rb, but it gives me the following errors:

```
# including "require 'action_cable/engine' "
 /home/ubuntu/workspace/config/application.rb:4:in `require': cannot load such file -- action_cable/engine (LoadError)
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config/application.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

and

```
# including "require 'action_cable' "
/home/ubuntu/workspace/config/application.rb:4:in `require': cannot load such file -- action_cable (LoadError)
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config/application.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Because Rails 5 is meant to have actioncable pre-loaded, I have not included any gems for it.

My config/routes.rb is:

```
include SessionsHelper

Rails.application.routes.draw do

  [...]
  mount ActionCable.server => '/cable'
  [...]
end
```

Comment: Could you add your gem file?

Comment: I did try that before and it didn't do anything, I'll try again and edit my post if it changes anything

Comment: Do you have 'actioncable' gem in your gemfile?

Comment: I tried adding the gem but it doesn't appear to be available anymore, bundle installing doesn't install it and visiting the gem page shows that it's no longer available as it's been integrated to rails.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is fixed- I don't know what happened but the app didn't upgrade properly and wasn't running as 5.1.5 after I tried upgrading it. I had to do it one more time and delete the following line from the config/application.rb : `config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true` in order to get it working.